# Hibernate: Not able to update to a new value if some value is present for a field

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm not able to update the field value to a **new value if there is already a value present**. Otherwise, if no value is present update is working fine.

Is there anything we need to perform additional to execute an update if there is some value present for the field. And I'm not seeing any error as well.

I'm using Hibernate 5.1 and PostgreSQL

**EntityClass**

```
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class TableA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "columnA")
    private String columnA;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Calendar createdDate;

    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Calendar updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "columnB")
    private java.util.Calendar columnB;

    @Column(name = "columC")
    private String columC;
}
```

**Batch Update method**:

```
   public void updateBatchTableAData(List<TableA> tableAList) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            log.info("Executing batch source Data");
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            IntStream.range(0, tableAList.size())
                     .filter(index -> tableAList.get(index) != null)
                     .forEach(index -> {
                         session.update(tableAList.get(index));
                         if (index % 100 == 0) {
                             session.flush();
                             session.clear();
                         }
                     });
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(
                    "Exception occurred while saving Batch TableA Data to the DB.", e);
        }
        session.close();
    }
```

**Fetch content Method**

```
public List getTableAData() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TableA.class);
            return criteria.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred while trying to fetch TableA data", e);
        }
    }
```

**update method**

```
   public void executeMethod(){
        List<TableA> tableAList = new ArrayList();
        getTableAData().forEach(data -> {
            TableA tableA = (TableA) data;
            tableA.setColumnB(null);
            tableA.setColumnC("newmodified_value");
            tableAList.add(tableA);
        });
        updateBatchTableAData(tableAList);
    }
```

**SessionFactory**

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public SessionFactory getPostgresqlSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, CURRENT_SESSION_PROPERTY_VALUE);
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, SetupConstants.POSTGRES_DRIVER);
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.URL,
                getDbURL());
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.USER, getUsername());
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.PASS, getPassword());
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.RELEASE_CONNECTIONS, RELEASE_CONNECTIONS_VALUE);
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, POSTGRESQL_DIALECT);
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.SHOW_SQL, SHOW_SQL_VALUE);
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, HBM2DDL_AUTO_VALUE);
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.AUTOCOMMIT, "true");
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, String.valueOf(BATCH_SIZE));
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.ORDER_INSERTS, ORDER_INSERTS_VALUE);
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.ORDER_UPDATES, "true");
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.BATCH_VERSIONED_DATA, "true");
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .build();
        MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
        Reflections entityPackageReflections = new Reflections("PACKAGE_NAME");
        entityPackageReflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class).forEach(metadataSources::addAnnotatedClass);
        Metadata metadata = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
        return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to debug your code execution? Also, have do you call your service/dao method from the controller?

Comment: Yes. I debugged. Im able to see the updated values for the TableA before session.flush. I'm calling these methods using the guice injector. For me update is working fine if the particular field is not having any value in it. Only if there is some value already present then update is not happening

Comment: is your question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Very unclear calling flow at a question.
My suggestion next time just describe exactly step by step what are you calling at your application.
It looks like you wrote it at reverse order.

For now, I see some silly mistakes at code.
It is difficult to understand if it is a reason to fail. However, you could try it and see the result.

***First place:***

```
public List<TableA> getTableAData() {
    List<TableA> list = new ArrayLsit<>();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
       Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TableA.class);
       list = criteria.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred while trying to fetch TableA data", e);
    } finally {
      if (session.isOpen()) {
          session.close();
      }
    }
    return list;
}
```

***Second place:***

You don't need to call `session.flush()` if you will call commit for a transaction later. `transactoin.commit()` will do it automatically.

I couldn't understand why the following check has done: `index % 100`? 
If it is mandatory please write a comment about why it should be used there.
Also, no idea why do you use `IntRange` class for iterating through a list? You don't use any methods from `IntRange`. You can use a stream for iterating through the list.

Much better will be replacing `update()` with `saveOrUpdate()`. It should be more logical with functionality which you want to provide -> if no appropriate entity found just save it. Otherwise, update it.

```
public void updateBatchTableAData(List<TableA> tableAList) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        log.info("Executing batch source Data");
        session.beginTransaction();
        tableAList.stream()
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .forEach(element -> session.saveOrUpdate(element));
        session.getTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception occurred while saving Batch TableA Data to the DB.", e);
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

***Third place:***

Difficult to understand your flow from your code snippets. If I understood from your question that you have a problem when your entity has already set any value.

You could check if this element has already any item or saved to DB. If yes you can use [org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-).

After updating data save it back to DB.